# Regressing panel data in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas, dataset, panel, regression

I am now looking at a panel dataset on which I have to regress. Since I only started my Phd this semester together with the econometrics courses I am still new to many statistic applications and regression methods. 
I want to do a simple regression as in Y = x1 x2 x3 etc, now I already browsed through some literature and found that for panel data it's common to do a fixed effects regression. Also, my Y variable only has positive values so I was thinking in the direction of a Tobit model?

I'm doing some research concerning the coverage of analysts in the financial business. My independent variable is the coverage of analysts on a certain firm, so per observation i have 1 analyst and 1 firm, together with different characteristics(market cap and betas etc) of the firm. All this data is monthly. As coverage cannot become negative (only 0) I was thinking of a Tobit model?

Do you have any ideas what would be a good regression method? Or have some good sources (e books, written books, through university I have access to almost anything concerning my field of work) of information (cause I do have to learn these things for future research)?

Comment: You are planning a complicated analysis, and you really should consult your friendly neighborhood statistician. I have no clue what your outcome measure ("coverage of analysts") looks like, but I doubt Tobit regression is the right choice: it is usually for situations when there is a detection threshold - small values cannot be measured precisely but are known to be smaller than a cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed effects regression will be wrong.  Your data are correlated across months, at least.  In SAS/STAT you would use proc glimmix.  SAS/ETS may have other procs which can do tobit links.  Maybe proc qlim?  For a first-year grad student this is pretty advanced.  Suggest you get some help from a more senior colleague.